# Error: 'socket' object has no attribute 'create_connection'

Tags: python, sockets

I have been trying to connect to a remote server with python socket for that I am using create_connection but when my client tries to connect to that server it shown this error

```
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'create_connection'
```

Here is my code

```
    def _connect(self):
        print("Connecting to ",self.hostname,self.port)
        self.sock.create_connection((self.hostname, self.port))
        print("Connection successfull")
```

Hostname and port is initialized in Constructor

```
    def __init__(self, host, port, path, headers, method):
        self.host = host.decode('utf-8')
        self.hostname = socket.gethostbyname(self.host)
        self.port = port
        self.path = path.decode('utf-8')
        self.header = headers
        self.method = method.decode('utf-8')
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Host and port is parsed from urlparse library

```
def from_url(cls, url, header, method):
        """Construct a request for the specified URL."""
        res = urlparse(url)
        path = res.path
        if res.query:
            path += b'?' + res.query
        return cls(res.hostname, res.port or 80, path, header, method)
```

Comment: What's `self.sock` equal to?

Comment: @TomDanilov self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Answer (score 1):

`create_connection` is a function in the `socket` module, not a method of the `socket.socket` class.

Furthermore, `create_connection` *returns* a `socket.socket` instance, so rather than creating one in `__init__`, you should set `self.sock` to some "uninitialized" value (e.g. `None`) in `__init__` and assign the new `socket.socket` instance in `_connect`:

Replace

> ```
> def __init__(self, …):
>     # …
>     self.sock = socket.socket(…)
>
> def _connect(self):
>     # …
>     self.sock.create_connection((self.hostname, self.port))
> ```

by

```
 def __init__(self, …):
     # …
     self.sock = None

 def _connect(self):
     # …
     self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.hostname, self.port))
```